# What does _id mean in Mongo $group operator

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple query in MongoDB as:

```
{ $group : { _id : { color: "$color", transport: "$transport"} , count : { $sum : 1 } } }
```

It means query in sql as:

```
select color, transport,count(1) from t group by color, transport
```

I would ask what `_id` means in the above mongodb query, if i change `_id` to any other string,such as `groupBy`, the error is: groupBy is not an aggregation operator,looks it has to be `_id` and can't be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation-framework in mongodb has some stages and operators and these operators have some expressions which can only work inside these stages.

Here `_id` is the expression which signifies the term with which you want to group with `(group by color)`. And such like that [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) is the accumulator for the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to `count` the number of documents which gets associated with that [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)ed term.

Comment: Thanks @ashh. You mean that `_id` is the fixed expression(key) to signify the group by terms?

Comment: @Tom Yes. And that is why mongodb so called as NoSQL database

Comment: What it means when `_id: 1`